# Does the long form of an abbreviation go in quotes?

Tags: abbreviations, acronyms

I am trying to use and introduce an abbreviation in a sentence. Example:

> I worked with technologies such as Syntactically Awesome Stylesheets (Sass) while working on my project.

Does the "Syntactically Awesome Stylesheets" part need to be in quotes? It seems a bit out-of-place to me while using an acronym with such a peculiar long form.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. In conventional writing on technical subjects, we do not use quotes.  However, you may want to check with the relevant style guide, if any.

Comment: Beat me to it. And if this was for a resume, remove the reference to yourself, start the sentence something like "Worked with..." or more assertive like "Awesome at Syntactically Awesome Stylesheets..." (depending on the employer a little tongue-in-cheek helps)

Comment: Nevermind the split-second. :-)  Change your comment to an answer, it's got a point to make  of its own.